# What is the DOS search pattern expression to find files named "Main" with any integer extension?

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-rename

I have a program that generated unknown numbers of files with integer extension as follows.

[image]

I want to append `.eps` to each. How to do this in a DOS batch file?

I cannot use the following because I don't know the search expression.

```
for %%x in (Main.<what>) do rename "%%x" "%%x.eps"
```

Note: Any files having the same name with non-integer extension must be left as is.

Comment: And when you say 'integer extensions', you mean 2- or 4-digit ones just as well as 3-digit ones (like on the picture), don't you?

Comment: @Andriy: the extension length vary from 3-digit 000 to 5-digit 99999, but in my situation 3-digit is more than enough.

Comment: Ah, that's a pity they can be zero-padded. I'll have to think of something else then.

Comment: Why not just count from 001 to 99999, check if the file is there and rename it?

Comment: @Fozi: Not necessary, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (Main.*) do (
    set ext=%%~Xx
    set /a num=!ext:~1!
    if !num! gtr 0 rename "%%x" "%%x.eps"
)
```

First SET get just the extension of file name, including the dot (with ~X). Second SET /A try to convert the extension (without the dot with :~1) to number. If it is really a number (greater than zero) do the rename.

Comment: There might be issues with numbers that start with 0s. In batch scripting, such numbers are considered to be in octal notation, and thus values like `083`, `097` would cause errors in the `SET /A` command. Same goes about values that start with decimal digits but also contain some letters. The command shell would attempt to treat such a value as hexadecimal, and if contained letters outside the range from `A` to `F` (case-insensitive), an error would occur.

Answer (score 1):

This should loop through the directory. Here is the explanation on how it works:

**tokens** = *1-2* means we only care about the first and second part of the file name.

**delims** = `.` means to split the tokens on the `.` in the file name.

`dir /b` means to only list the files, don't show any of the `.` or `..` that is normally shown in the `dir` command. You need to put the directory in there or run from the same file directory.

`LSS` a `char` will always return *GREATER THAN*, that's how this works. I picked 9999, you can pick whatever.

Finally, it takes the first part of the file name (`%%A`) and then the extension (`%%B`) then renames to first part of the file name (`%%A`) with the `eps` extension.

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=." %%A in ('dir /b') do if %%B LSS 9999 rename %%A.%%B %%A.%%B.eps
```

Put this in your batch file and run it.

Note: You can't rename to the same filename, so I used `%%A.%%B.eps`.

Comment: Assuming that works at all, how would it avoid renaming files with non-numeric extensions?

Comment: @Carey: The numerics have nothing to do with it. The extension is treated as a "token" because we specify the delimiter as the period, so it splits on the period. I just tried it here and it works.

Comment: Add an IF expression for the second (%%B) token like in the answer above it think it will work - at least it will work little better than in my answer - it will still rename star.00XXX.star ((((

Comment: The OP said "Note: Any files having the same name with non-integer extension must be left as is."

Comment: @Carey: Fixed. Added IF statement.